# Univariate autoregression with random forest to forecast 4 steps ahead

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, random-forest, forecasting

I have been trying to do time series forecasting with Random Forest following some examples like [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/random-forest-for-time-series-forecasting/) and [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/09/time-series-forecasting-with-random-forest/). However, it is still not clear to me how to predict values that are beyond the last data point in the time series.

I have a univariate time series with weekly frequency of about 5 years of historical data, with just `date` and `value` fields, which I would like to use to forecast 4 steps ahead (time horizon = 4), using past values (autoregression). I have processed the dataset so the original vector of values became a matrix where the first column is the original data, and the other columns are the lagged versions of it (e.g. `t-1`, `t-2`, ..., `t-n`, where `n` is a lag I can decide).

An example with `lag = 4`:

```
date,value,value.l1,value.l2,value.l3,value.l4
2017-01-01,1070,NA,NA,NA,NA
2017-01-08,603,1070,NA,NA,NA
2017-01-15,1788,603,1070,NA,NA
2017-01-22,38,1788,603,1070,NA
2017-01-29,1894,38,1788,603,1070
...
2023-02-26,2420,5550,871,623,1059
```

Practically, since my last data point is dated `2023-02-26`, I would like to predict the values for `2023-03-05`, `2023-03-12`, `2023-03-19` and `2023-03-26`.

I understand I should use the lagged values as the features (or predictors) for the random forest, but it is not clear to me how this structure of the data could allow me to predict data points beyond the last one (`2023-02-26`).

My initial idea was to set the number of lags equal to the desired time horizon (as in the example above), to expand the original matrix to include the future dates I am interested in, and used the available lagged values in each date to forecast using the model fitted on past data. However, this way I am missing some data as I move forward.

An example of the extended matrix (the first column is the target I want to predict, the others the predictors):

```
date,value,value.l1,value.l2,value.l3,value.l4
2023-03-05,NA,2420,5550,871,623
2023-03-12,NA,NA,2420,5550,871
2023-03-19,NA,NA,NA,2420,5550
2023-03-26,NA,NA,NA,NA,2420
```

As you can see, in `2023-03-26` I have only `value.l4` for making predictions.

Another idea would be to predict only 1 step ahead at a time for 4 times, and use the forecasted values at each step as (lagged) predictors for the next time step (basically, filling the missing values with the predictions). However, I think this could worsen the predictions depending on the accuracy of the algorithm.

I am not sure this is the correct way to do it, so I am asking for a help to hopefully solve this issue.

I am aware there are other techniques for this type of problems (e.g. ARIMA), but I really want to test this with a machine learning technique so that I could hopefully apply other algorithms other than random forest.

**EDIT**

Actually, I just gave it a go, and it could not work as I was thinking, since random forest is rightly complaining about the absence of the response value in the training set once I reach the dates that are beyond the original time series.

Therefore my idea is now to compute 1 step ahead forecasts even for the past values so that I have data to calculate error metrics. For every date in the dataset, I would do this in a loop:

1. train the model using a number of past observations (saying 100), using the lagged features as predictors
2. predict 1 step ahead using the fitted model and the lagged predictors at time `t+1`

Once I reach the dates that have no available data in the response column, I would fill these missing values using the predictions calculated in the previous loop iteration, that will in turn become (a small) part of the training set in the next loop iteration.

I will update this post with the results.